# Differential privacy and probability problem

Tags: probability

I was reading an [interesting article](https://accuracyandprivacy.substack.com/p/differential-privacy-an-easy-case) on differential privacy (the article itself is not relevant for the problem) and in it it presents the following situation:

Consider you take a survey, where each of your respondents gets a question that they can answer with yes or no. For each answer, you do the following: flip a coin that has a known probability $p$ to land heads. If it lands heads, keep the original answer, otherwise, flip the answer (yes becomes no, no becomes yes).

Consider that $100$ people participate in your survey.  Of those $100$ people, $35$ people answer with yes. After the random flipping, you observe "yes" $48$ times. Considering that you only see the outcome after the randomization process ($48$ out of a $100$ "yes" answers): how can we estimate the original fraction of people that answered "yes".

In the article it gives the following formula: $\frac{0.48 - (1 - p)}{p - (1-p)}$

The numerator kind of makes sense to me: It is the fraction of the yes count that you observe minus the probability that someone initially answered no, but the answer got flipped. However, I do not understand what the denominator represents and how to get to it. Is it possible to get to the above formula using just the basic rules of probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, who says yes?  There are two types:

Type I:  Those who intended "yes" and got $H$.  Let's let $\psi$ denote the portion that intended yes, so then Type I has $\psi\times p$ people.

Type II:  those who intended "no" and got $T$.  As $1-\psi$ is the portion that intended no, Type II has $(1-\psi)\times (1-p)$ people.

We are told that $$\psi\times p+(1-\psi)\times (1-p)=.48$$

Solving that for $\psi$ yields $$\boxed { \psi = \frac {.48+p-1}{2p-1}}$$ as desired.